# wkwebview auto fill login form swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, autofill, wkwebview

im new in the Swift World. I have a big problem ...
I've tried to write an app that has only one WKWebView. It is like a web browser.
The app should be able to fill die LogIn Fields automatically from an object or a list. But for test reasons i have put the login data into variables.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , WKNavigationDelegate{

// Zugänge
let pw : String = "test"
let bn : String = "test@test.com"
// Adresse
let adresse : String = "https://www.facebook.com"

var webView: WKWebView!

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    title = webView.title
}
override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: adresse)!
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

i think this is possible with JS but i don't know how.

Is there any way so solve my Problem?

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.  (otherwise, apps would be able to steal your passwords)

Comment: is this salesforce login page?

Answer (score 8):

This is actually doable using 1Password

Add the extension files:

- OnePasswordExtension.h
- OnePasswordExtension.m

Then include them using a bridging header:

```
#import "OnePasswordExtension.h"
```

Finally, you can use the following in your project

```
@IBAction func onePassword_btn(sender: AnyObject) {
OnePasswordExtension.sharedExtension().fillLoginIntoWebView(self.webView, forViewController: self, sender: sender, completion: {(Bool) in
// error handling
})
}
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/AgileBits/onepassword-app-extension) to the 1Password

Here is the [reference](http://sofc.developer-works.com/article/20353217/how+do+i+enable+autofill+password+for+a+wkwebview)

or you can simply try like this

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {

    let savedUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("USERNAME")
    let savedPassword = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("PASSWORD")

    if savedUsername == nil || savedPassword == nil {return}

    if ( countElements(savedUsername!) != 0 && countElements(savedPassword!) != 0) {
        let loadUsernameJS = "var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='username']\"); \\ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = \'\(savedUsername)\';}"
        let loadPasswordJS = "var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name='password']\"); \\ for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = \'\(savedPassword)\';}"

        self.webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadUsernameJS)
        self.webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadPasswordJS)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This IS actually doable using [1Password](https://github.com/AgileBits/onepassword-app-extension)

### Steps to implement it in Swift

Add the extension files:

- `OnePasswordExtension.h`
- `OnePasswordExtension.m`

Then include them using a bridging header:

`#import "OnePasswordExtension.h"`

Finally, you can use the following in your project

```
@IBAction func onePassword_btn(sender: AnyObject) {
    OnePasswordExtension.sharedExtension().fillLoginIntoWebView(self.webView, forViewController: self, sender: sender, completion: {(Bool) in
        // error handling
    })
}
```

Comment: But it requires 1Password app to be installed

Comment: Yes, I've notices that a lot of apps have embraced it, and it's a great UX for the many people who do.

Comment: Can you share how you performed it in salesforce sdk? @jackreichert