# Autofill works fine in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm trying to implement Autofill in a `WKWebview`. It works fine when I run it in the simulator. However, when I run it on a physical device, it doesn't ask me if I want to save the credentials. If I save the credentials manually then I can do Autofill.

Xcode throws me the following error:

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25293 ""example.com" failed
>   to approve "BundleID"" UserInfo={NSDescription="example.com" failed to
>   approve "BundleID"}

Comment: Maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777944/wkwebview-auto-fill-login-form-swift-2

Comment: thanks for the quick response. it does not help me, because I want to save the credentials to the iOS build in keychain and not to 1password.

Comment: @Sacha you got any solution i have facing same issue